# Let $p,q$ be prime numbers , Find all the solutions to the congruence $x^2\equiv (p+q)x \pmod{pq}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $p,q$ be prime numbers , find all the solutions to the congruence $x^2\equiv (p+q)x \pmod{pq}$

***Attempt:***

$$x^2\equiv (p+q)x \pmod{pq} \Longrightarrow \cases {x^2\equiv (p+q)x \pmod{p}\\x^2\equiv (p+q)x \pmod{q}} $$

For $\pmod{p}$

$$x^2\equiv (p+q)x \pmod{p} \Longrightarrow x(x-(p+q))\equiv 0 \pmod{p}$$

Because $p$ is prime number then  we can write :

$$x\equiv 0 \pmod{p}\space\space\space(1)$$
and
$$x\equiv (p+q) \pmod{p}\Longrightarrow x\equiv q \pmod{p}\space\space\space(2)$$

For $\pmod{q}$

$$x^2\equiv (p+q)x \pmod{q} \Longrightarrow x(x-(p+q))\equiv 0 \pmod{q}$$

Because $q$ is prime number then  we can write :

$$x\equiv 0 \pmod{q}\space\space\space(3)$$
and
$$x\equiv (p+q) \pmod{q}\Longrightarrow x\equiv p \pmod{q}\space\space\space(4)$$

Now, we can say because $(1)$ and $(3)$ that $x\equiv 0 \pmod{pq}$.

There are more solutions using $(2)$ and $(4)$ but I cannot see a legal way to solve them.

**Edit:** note that $p,q$ **can**(not must) be equal to one another, which I think is another case for a solution.

Comment: Write $x^2 - (p+q)x$ as $(x-p)(x-q) - pq$.

Comment: @Aqua: and $x\equiv p+q\bmod pq$

Comment: @Dr.Mathva Thank you, would you care to explain how to get to that answer.

Comment: @IsaacS I've added an answer

Comment: Same as in the linked dupes, except you have roots $p,q$ vs $−2,−3$ or $0,1$. See the comments here. Same question was asked a [few days ago](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3960566/242).

Answer (score 0):

Your ‘and’ should be ‘or’.

**Hint**:

You just have to use the inverse isomorphism of the isomorphism of the *Chinese remainder theorem*, which relies on a Bézout's identity: $\enspace up+vq=1$, between $p$ and $q:$

> The system of congruences $\begin{cases}x\equiv a\mod p,\\x\equiv b\mod q,\end{cases}$ has as solution
> $\enspace x\equiv b up+a vq\mod pq.$